# How do I evaluate JavaScript and get a result in a Xamarin iOS project?

Tags: javascript, ios, json, xamarin

I have a bunch of JavaScript functions as strings that I want to evaluate and get the result from in a Xamarin iOS application. I'd like to be able to pass some other String of JSON to the JavaScript for the function to use.

I don't mind using a web view but this should all happen in the background and the user shouldn't see anything.

As a simple example, let's say I want to evaluate a function that grabs two values out of the incoming JSON called `first` and `second` and then returns the sum of those two values. Both the function and the JSON are in `string` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JINT](http://sebastienros.com/jint-2.0) is a .NET Javascript engine that is supposed to be Xamarin friendly.

Comment: Wow. Jint looks pretty awesome!

Answer (score 1):

On iOS I would use WKWebView as its JS engine is much much faster than UIWebView's. You can use [EvaluateJavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:) method to pass in the JavaScript.

I have created a hybrid WebView control for Xamarin Forms which provides a 2-way bridge between C# and JS on all the 3 mobile platforms. It wouldn't work for your application but it can provide some helpful tips on how to run JavaScript on iOS. This iOS portion [adds callback functions from JS to C#.](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/HybridWebView/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs#L102-L114) This [runs JS on the WKWebView control](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/HybridWebView/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs#L152-L158). If you want to test it in action the sample application on that GitHub repository has several sample pages to run.